# how to make layout to work on all size in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell how to make layout to work on all size in android.if I used support screen  is it work for all screen size ? can anybody tell how to do?

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]                            
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]  
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]  
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]                   
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]    
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]                   
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"                  
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"                  
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a separate layout for each screen size.  There are several factors affecting the layout per screen such as screen density, size, orientation, and resolution.  It would be hard to make one layout that would work **well** on all Android screen sizes.

You should determine which screen sizes are best to support, and create layouts for targeting those.

Please read through the best practices here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

Any layout will work with any device's screen size.
`support-screens` manifest tag is aimed to restrict different devices (which is incompatible with your restrictions) from acessing your app through market.

Answer (score 1):

see

```
 <supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```